# What type of clippers is suggested for berry picking?

Tags: tools, berries

I was watching a youtube video on picking sea buckthorn, and was wondering what type of shears they were using.

Video about the tools I was wondering about:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXy3w27_Zz8

another video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8TIHsukiQI

Answer (score 3):

> what type of shears they were using

In the Comments to the first video (both shown as posted by Leons Choice) 'Leon'  mentions: *these tools I made by myself*.

Here are some other tools used by Leon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QP6sBLcYeXQ.

A lot less persnickety but rather cruder tool can be made from very heavy gauge wire bent into a tight `U` shape (with spiraling of the blunt end if necessary to add springiness) and the sharp ends bent at right angles but parallel to one another. Something vaguely like the top pair of needle-nose pliers [here](http://www.halfords.com/workshop-tools/tools/hand-tools/sealey-ak8568-needle-nose-pliers-set-3pc-280mm) but with a spring in the handle so the points open when the tool is not squeezed.

For the large scale there are alternatives :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Spgc-REEUa4